# #Hibernate is it necessary to save each object that is part of composite-key before saving one that contains it?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-key

I have 3 entities. Lest Call it A,B,C and the 4th one that has composite key that is combination of IDs.

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private String id;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private String id;
}


@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "c", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ClassWithCompositeKey> relations = new ArrayList<ClassWithCompositeKey>();

}

@Entity
public class ClassWithCompositeKey {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected CompositeKey compositeKey;

    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private A a;

    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private B b;

    @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private C c;

    public ClassWithCompositeKey(A a, B b, C c) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = c;
       this.compositeKey = new CompositeKey(a.getId(),b.getId(),c.getId());
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "A_ID", columnDefinition = "raw")
    private String aId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "B_ID", columnDefinition = "raw")
    private String bId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "C_ID", columnDefinition = "raw")
    private String cId;

    public CompositeKey(String aId, String bId, String cId) {
        this.aId = aId;
        this.bId = bId;
        this.cId = cId;
    }
}
```

Then when I'm trying to save:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
entityManager.persist(a);
entityManager.persist(b);
//I'm not saving C
ClassWithCompositeKey classWithCompositeKey = new ClassWithCompositeKey(a, b, c);
c.getRelations().add(classWithCompositeKey);
entityManager.persist(c);
```

I'm getting exception 
`"ConstraintViolationException: Column 'C_ID' cannot be null"`

It's because c.id is null before "c" will be saved but this value goes to the CompositeKey instance.

I would like to save "c" and have saved collection of ClassWithCompositeKey automatically. However now I first have to save "c" after that attach ClassWithCompositeKey instance to it and save it.
It is possible (maybe by using other kind of mapping) to have C and ClassWithCompositeKey saved by cascade in one "persist" call ?

Answer (score 0):

Only at the time of persist you will get the generated value at C, Thats reason you get exception.

Beacuse hibernate will update the generated value only after insert operation. It will first insert and then update the join column.

In the above scenario, you have C_ID of c class which is primary key mapped to C_ID of ClassWithCompositeKey which is again primarykey, and obivious primary key cannot be null.

So try re deign your ClassWithCompositeKey with foreign key columns.

Comment: Ok, I know why the exception is being thrown. I'm asking if it's possible to do it other way and achieve the goal which is save everything at once. Redesign of data model is not an option here.
Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Dear Lukasz, did you find a way to save everything at once?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to setup your cascade options in the composite key fields to at least cascade the persist operation.

Comment: Doesn't work. The Id's are string values and they won't be magically initialized after any cascade operation and still will be `null`s

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are marking some columns as "insertable = false" and as "optional = false" at the same time in the ClassWithCompositeKey class.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private A a;
```

**You don't even need this columns!!** remove the a, b and c columns in this class, you already have them in your Embedded Id if you need them:

```
ClassWithCompositeKey yourClass = ...;
//any initialization code
yourClass.getCompositeKey().getA();
yourClass.getCompositeKey().getB();
yourClass.getCompositeKey().getC();
```

Comment: In `CompositeKey` I have only `Id's` of those objects (not the Objects) and I really need those references in `ClassWithCompositeKey ` this object. Moreover I don't believe that would fix the problem.

Comment: You can actually use the objects instead of just the id's inside the composite key, just don't declare the fields as String but as A, B and C respectively, and then you can use them as I point out

Comment: I tried to use this approach. I removed properties from `ClassWithCompositeKey`. I replaced String id's in `CompositeKey` with references to objects.
Unfortunately it results with:
`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(AbstractTypeDescriptor.java:88)`